# Angular 8 return Observable<boolean> from function

Tags: angular

How to return `Observable<boolean>` true `after` `this.Form = new FormGroup(formControls);` in function `GetDataFromService()`?

**Html**

```
<form *ngIf="loading | async" [formGroup]="Form" class="example-form">
</form>
<mat-spinner *ngIf="!loading | async"></mat-spinner>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-product-dialog',
  templateUrl: './add-product-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-product-dialog.component.css']
})
export class AddProductDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  properties: any;
  Form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  loading: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddProductDialogComponent>,
    private http: HttpClient) {

    this.loading = this.GetDataFromService();
  }

  GetDataFromService(): Observable<Boolean> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    let formControls: { [key: string]: AbstractControl } = {};

    this.http.get("https://localhost:44346/api/Values/GetDrillsProperties", { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => {
      this.properties = data

      Object.keys(this.properties).forEach(element => {
        formControls[element] = new FormControl();
      });

      this.Form = new FormGroup(formControls);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: assign the this.http.get() to a result variable and return it

Comment: without subscribing here

Comment: There's no reason to use an Observable<Boolean>. The loading flag is not asynchronous. When you start loading, set a boolean flag to true. When you've finished loading, set it to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a return keyword to you get call and return boolean after `this.form` like

```
return this.http.get("https://localhost:44346/api/Values/GetDrillsProperties", { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => {
      this.properties = data

      Object.keys(this.properties).forEach(element => {
        formControls[element] = new FormControl();
      });

      this.Form = new FormGroup(formControls);
      return true;
    });
```

But instead of making loading async why not just change it to boolean like

```
loading:boolean=true;

this.GetDataFromService().subscribe(d=>{
//here set loading to false
})
```

and on html use like

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can import map from 'rxjs/operators' and use it

```
return this.http.get("https://localhost:44346/api/Values/GetDrillsProperties", { headers: headers }).pipe(map(res => {
  this.properties = res

  Object.keys(this.properties).forEach(element => {
    formControls[element] = new FormControl();
  })

  this.Form = new FormGroup(formControls);
  return true;
})) as Observable<boolean>;
```